# Hyperparameter Optimization with Hyperopt (Baysian Hyperparamter Optimization) yields hyperparamter outside defined search space

Tags: optimization, xgboost, hyperparameters, hyperopt

I implemented a hyperparameter optimization with hyperopt for a XGBoostClassifier.
Therefore, I defined a certain search space, e.g. `"n_estimators": hp.choice("n_estimators",np.arange(32, 264, 8, dtype=int))`

However, hyperopt recommends 18 "n_estimators", which is outside the defined search space.

Is this a "normal" expected behavior, that could happen? If yes, why? Otherwise I think, I defined the search space incorrectly.

I appreciate any help or explanations.

Edit 1: Reproducible example:

```
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score, f1_score, accuracy_score, recall_score, average_precision_score, roc_auc_score
import xgboost as xgb
from hyperopt import STATUS_OK, Trials, fmin, hp, tpe

# Search space
space={
        "n_estimators": hp.choice("n_estimators",np.arange(32, 264, 8, dtype=int)),                   # tune 32 - 256
        "eta":hp.uniform("eta",0.01,0.9),                                   # learning rate # tune 0.01 - 0.9
        "gamma":hp.uniform("gamma",0.01,0.9),                               # tune 0 - 0.9
        "max_depth":hp.choice("max_depth", np.arange(6, 18, 1, dtype=int)),                       # tune 6 - 18
        "min_child_weight":hp.quniform('min_child_weight', 0, 10, 1),       # tune 0 - 10
        "subsample":hp.uniform("subsample",0.5,1),                          # tune 0.5 - 1
        "colsample_bytree":hp.uniform("colsample_bytree",0,1),              # tune 0- 1
        "colsample_bylevel":hp.uniform("colsample_bylevel",0,1),             # tune 0- 1
        "colsample_bynode":hp.uniform("colsample_bynode",0,1),              # tune 0- 1
        "scale_pos_weight": 1,                  # tune by class imbalance: (sum(negative instances) / sum(positive instances)                  
    }

def objective(space):
        params={     
                # General parameters
                "booster":'gbtree',
                "nthread":16,
                
                # Booster parameters
                "n_estimators":space["n_estimators"],           # tune 32 - 256
                "eta":space["eta"],                               # learning rate # tune 0.01 - 0.9
                "gamma":space["gamma"],                           # tune 0 - 0.9
                "max_depth":space["max_depth"],                   # tune 6 - 18
                "min_child_weight":space["min_child_weight"],     # tune 0 - 10
                "subsample":space["subsample"],                   # tune 0.5 - 1
                "colsample_bytree":space["colsample_bytree"],     # tune 0- 1
                "colsample_bylevel":space["colsample_bylevel"],   # tune 0- 1
                "colsample_bynode":space["colsample_bynode"],     # tune 0- 1
                "scale_pos_weight":space["scale_pos_weight"],     # tune by class imbalance: (sum(negative instances) / sum(positive instances))
                
                # Learning task parameters
                "objective":"multi:softmax", # multi:softprob
                "num_class":2,
                #eval_metric="auc", # default metric will be assigned according to objective, logloss for classification
                "seed":42,
                }
        
        clf=xgb.XGBClassifier(**params)                      
                        
        evaluation = [( X_valid, y_valid)]
        
        clf.fit(X_train, y_train, eval_set=evaluation,
                verbose=False)
        
        preds = clf.predict_proba(X_valid)

        predicted_classes = preds.argmax(axis=1) # extract the class with the highest probability

        f1 = f1_score(y_valid, predicted_classes)
        acc = accuracy_score(y_valid, predicted_classes)
        recall = recall_score(y_valid, predicted_classes)
        precision = precision_score(y_valid, predicted_classes)
        average_precision = average_precision_score(y_valid, predicted_classes)
        roc_auc = roc_auc_score(y_valid, predicted_classes)

        return {'loss': -f1, 'status': STATUS_OK, 'f1': f1, 'acc': acc, 'recall': recall, 'precision': precision, 'average_precision': average_precision, 'roc_auc': roc_auc}

trials = Trials()

best_hyperparams = fmin(fn = objective,
                        space = space,
                        algo = tpe.suggest,
                        max_evals = 10,
                        trials = trials,
                        rstate = np.random.default_rng(42))

print("The best hyperparameters are : ")
print(best_hyperparams)
print(trials.best_trial["result"])
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: You'd need to provide a dataset for this to be a reprex, although the code is potentially helpful by itself.  // I ran `hyperopt.pyll.stochastic.sample(space)` a number of times and the parameters all look OK.

Comment: First of all, thanks for checking. I think the example is data independent. No matter what my data looks like (and whether it makes sense), hyperopt should find parameters that fall within the search space. This is for n_estimators and max_depth not the case based on my code. Maybe it is related to hp.choice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the output of `fmin` for `choice` hyperparameters is the *index* of the hyperparameter in the list of choices: https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt/issues/284

If you have a look at `trials.__dict__` at the end of your code, you'll find that all the values of `n_estimators` are integers between 0 and 28, the length of your list of options but none in the actual list.