# Hyperopt being non deterministic with XGBRegressor

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, xgboost, grid-search

I ran a hyperparameter searching using hyperopt.

Defined the space and objective.

```py
# Define the search space for hyperparameters
space = {
    'n_estimators': hp.quniform('n_estimators', 100, 500, 10),
    'max_depth': hp.choice('max_depth', range(1, 20, 2)),
    'min_child_weight': hp.quniform('min_child_weight', 1, 10, 1),
    'gamma': hp.uniform('gamma', 0, 1),
    'subsample': hp.uniform('subsample', 0.5, 1),
    'colsample_bytree': hp.uniform('colsample_bytree', 0.5, 1),
    'learning_rate': hp.loguniform('learning_rate', -4, 0),
    'reg_alpha': hp.uniform('reg_alpha', 0, 1),
    'reg_lambda': hp.uniform('reg_lambda', 0, 1)
}

def objective(params):
    params = {
        'n_estimators': int(params['n_estimators']),
        'max_depth': int(params['max_depth']),
        'min_child_weight': params['min_child_weight'],
        'gamma': params['gamma'],
        'subsample': params['subsample'],
        'colsample_bytree': params['colsample_bytree'],
        'learning_rate': params['learning_rate',]
        'reg_alpha': params['reg_alpha'],
        'reg_lambda': params['reg_lambda']
    }
    model = xgb.XGBRegressor(objective='reg:absoluteerror', enable_categorical=True, booster = 'gbtree', random_state = 42,  verbose=2,**params)
    model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
    Y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
    loss = abs(Y_test - Y_pred).mean()  # mean absolute error 
       
    return {'loss': loss, 'status': STATUS_OK}
```

Defined the trial parameters.

```py
trials = Trials()
best = fmin(fn=objective,
            space=space,
            algo=tpe.suggest,
            max_evals=400,
            trials=trials)

print("Best: {}".format(best))
```

However, when I pass the same parameters in the `best` variable into XGB explicitly as follows.

```py
### Experimental params here 
p = {'colsample_bytree': 0.7844038007128916,
  'gamma': 0.17639244252618205,
  'learning_rate': 0.9867329566851424,
  'max_depth': 9,
  'min_child_weight': 1.0,
  'n_estimators': 500,
  'reg_alpha': 0.7161477369968196,
  'reg_lambda': 0.04261895096213106,
  'subsample': 0.6494075038596621}

#objective ='reg:absoluteerror',enable_categorical = True, verbose = 2
model = xgb.XGBRegressor(objective='reg:absoluteerror', enable_categorical=True, booster = 'gbtree', random_state = 42,  verbose=2,**p)
model.fit(X_train, Y_train)

# Make prediction
Y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
```

I get a different `mean_absolute_error`.

Lets refer to the two losses as:

- Loss A = Loss from the hyperparameter search.
- Loss B = Loss when I explicitly pass parameters from the search into the model and compute the loss manually.

---

- The training splits are not being redefined.
- The model should be deterministic because of the random state. The difference in loss is far too large to explain randomness. (Loss B = 43 vs Loss A = 26)

Here is the part that gets interesting.

When I explicitly pass the `p` dict to the `objective` function, it returns Loss B.

Is some floating point shenanigans occuring?

Answer (score 0):

`fmin` returns index for `hp.choice`. Not the value. This is quite unintuitive.

Comment: Self-answered questions are cool and encouraged. Please make sure you leave it in a formathat may be useful to future readers (explicit title, trimmed code,... all that is recommended in [ask])

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77002096/10495893